# Содержит ли строка допустимое имя файла

Tags: c++

Есть ли готовая функция для проверки если строка содержит допустимое имя файла?
Язык С++.

Comment: Ссылка из удалённого анонимного ответа: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3001/Validating-file-names

Answer (score 2):

В .NET я бы воспользовался ф-цией [GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) и потом просканировал строчку на их наличие. В WinAPI наиболее подходящей является [PathFileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773584.aspx)

И давайте определимся со следующими моментами:

1. На какой ОС работаем? Понятно, что под линуксом запросто можно создать файлы с названиями вроде COM1, от чего Windows может снести крышу.
2. Какие файловые системы используем? На fat12 потенциально нельзя создать файлы с именами отличными от 8.3. А ограничения по кол-ву символов есть и на других ФС.
3. Нам это нужно, чтобы создать файл с каким-либо именем или мы просто берем от балды какой-то путь и что-то там делаем? И если это именно так, что почему мы изначально не пользуемся ф-циями работы с путями: они обязаны возвращать валидные значения. А при создании своего каталога-файла всегда нужно проверять коды ошибок и анализировать, где случился косяк (не хватило прав, не хватило места, носитель недоступен или неправильные символы в пути).

Answer (score 1):

Что Вы имеете в виду под понятием "Допустимое имя файла?"

Если нужно проверить, существует ли такой файл, то можно использовать функцию из Boost'а `boost::filesystem::exists()`

Comment: Под допустимое имя файла я имею ввиду если в этой строке нету символов < > : " / \ | ? * символы в пределах 0-31, или строка не является зарезервированное имя в DOS - CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9, и так далее.

Comment: А уважаемый учитывает, что в разных операционных системах (и даже файловых системах) разные ограничения?

Comment: Раз речь о "зарезервированное имя в DOS", то тут ограничения понятны :) Другое дело что в рамках "языка" этой функции быть не может, так как язык и платформа - разные сущности.